# addressing a value in data frame next to a certain value

Tags: python, selenium

trying to address a certain value in a data frame.

I got a CSV file that looks like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohJ3H.png)

I used the stock column as an index for a for loop. then I got historical price data from yahoo finance using selenium which I transformed into a data frame looks like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/721Gs.png)
I want to search the stock date in the data frame I got from yahoo finance.

```
for stock_symbol in mystocks:
yahoo_url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+stock_symbol+"/history?period1=0&period2=2597263000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
```

getting the data

```
bs_data = BeautifulSoup(source_data, features="lxml")
table = bs_data.find('table', attrs={"data-test": "historical-prices"})
dataf = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

I want to create a for loop that gets me the values from the wanted date row and puts it into a csv (stock name Date Open High Low Close* Adj Close** Volume).

the output I want is only a certain date from the CSV I got. for example in the CSV for CALM the date wanted is Apr 01, 2019 so I want to pull only this date data from the Yahoo data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert with BeautifulSoup, I took a stab at this by downloading the data in csv format to a default directory (chrome options) (there is a link to download)

This is by no means an answer to your question as you are using BeautifulSoup, but something you can consider.

```
import time
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

download_path = Path(r'C:\stackoverflow')

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": str(download_path),
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

driver = Remote(options=options)
stock_symbols = ['CALM', 'CTRA', 'NVGS', 'ANGO']

for stock_symbol in stock_symbols:
    driver.get(f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock_symbol}/history?period1=0&period2=2597263000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d')
    time.sleep(5) # Replace with Webdriver Wait

    download_data_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Data')
    file_name = download_data_link.get_attribute('download')
    download_data_link.click()

    file_path = download_path / file_name
    while True:
        if file_path.exists():
            break

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_path)
    df['Stock Name'] = stock_symbol
    print(df.head())

    break
```

**Output**

```
           Open    High      Low     Close  Adj Close   Volume Stock Name
 Date                                                                         
 1996-12-12  1.81250  1.8125  1.68750  1.703125   0.743409  1984400       CALM
 1996-12-13  1.71875  1.8125  1.65625  1.781250   0.777510   996800       CALM
 1996-12-16  1.81250  1.8125  1.71875  1.718750   0.750229   122000       CALM
 1996-12-17  1.75000  1.8125  1.75000  1.773425   0.774094   239200       CALM
 1996-12-18  1.81250  1.8125  1.75000  1.812500   0.791151   216400       CALM
```

**filter by date**

```
df = df.reset_index()
print(df.loc[df['Date'] == '1996-12-12'])

        Date    Open    High     Low     Close  Adj Close   Volume Stock 
Name
0 1996-12-12  1.8125  1.8125  1.6875  1.703125   0.743409  1984400       CALM
```

Comment: as for the download from Yahoo, I would love to change it to the way you did it, I just don't know how... I tried what you wrote but it gave me some errors.
`ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`
`urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0988AE90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
`
also, the output I want is only a certain date from the CSV I got for example only.

Comment: for example in the CSV for CALM the date wanted is **Apr 01, 2019** so I want to pull only this date data from the Yahoo data frame.

Comment: I have used remote driver, you may not have a selenium standalone server up, may be that is the reason why you are getting the Connection Error. Check your driver. I have updated the answer to filter by a given data. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much! this helps me a lot.
any chance you can guide me how to put up a standalone server up so i can download the CSV from YAHOO? instead of opening the chrome and scraping the data (your method will save a lot of time)

Comment: you can use chrome or firefox driver and download the csv file. The only reason I have used the remote driver is because of my local setup (Docker Selenium Grid). If you want to learn, this is a good place to start https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: well, I am using the chrome driver...
i think the problem is with the `Remote(options=options)` command. when i change it to where the driver is placed `webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")` then it downloads the csv but stops there then the program doesn't stop or give an error

Comment: dont forget to set the options. webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

Comment: i have a problem with the date at the end of the code `print(df.loc[df['Date'] == '1996-12-12'])` i dont want to enter a specific date i want it to adress to the csv and next to the stock symbol pull the date lets say its the CALM stock then `print(df.loc[df['Date'] == date that is next to stock symbol (from my csv)])`